# Yii Cookie Validation To Keep User Logged In

Tags: php, cookies, yii

I am trying to get cookies to keep the user logged in.  Here is what I have, but it's not working:

On my login form I have a "Remember Me" Checkbox, and I have this in my login function:

```
$duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30  : 0 ; // true = 30 days, false=until browser close
Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
```

In config/main.php I have:

```
'user'=>array(
                // enable cookie-based authentication
                'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                'autoRenewCookie'=>true,
                'loginUrl'=>'/site/login',
                'class' => 'WebUser',
            ),
```

and I have WebUser:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {


public function init()
{
    Yii::app()->getSession()->open();
    if($this->getIsGuest() && $this->allowAutoLogin && !Yii::app()->hasCommonSSL)
        $this->restoreFromCookie();
    elseif($this->autoRenewCookie && $this->allowAutoLogin)
        $this->renewCookie();

    $this->updateAuthStatus();
}
```

To test this I am logging in, then quitting the browser and reopening. I can confirm that restoreFromCookie() is getting called when reopening.
What I expected to happen is for afterLogin($fromCookie) to get called, but it doesn't.

So I did some digging.  I found that restoreFromCookie() calls

`$data=$app->getSecurityManager()->validateData($cookie->value))!==false`

in an if statement.  It never passes the validation. And I can't, for the life of me, figure out why!

Could anybody shed some light on this for me?

Thanks

Comment: Not saying that this causes the problem but you should call parent::init(). I see that you kind of rewrited it, but CWebUser init call the init method of CApplicationComponent and this init is also doing some stuff.

Comment: Ya, thanks for catching that, but your right, that didn't fix the problem.